# Swift - How to prevent from closing socket in force quit?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, notifications

My project works by socket and I try to make a chat app like whatsApp.
Now, My Problem is how I can keep open the socket even user kill app from AppSwitcher and goes my app to force quit mode? ( LIKE WhatsApp )
In another word, whatsApp and telegram and so on how can keep open the socket? Because when we send a message to another else , quickly comes a notification to her/his phone and notify her/his has a message and it's the opening socket result.
I search about it but I can't find a fine solution. 
Thanks for answers...

Comment: You need to use Pushkit to send a notification to re-launch your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use APNS.
If the app is killed your socket will be closed... so simple.
When an user send a message to another one which isn't online your server should send also a notification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Can you explain more

Comment: Sure, in my "user to user" chat, for instance, the socket send also information about the left user status (online or offline), then the socket on server send also an Apple push notification to the left user if he is offline. So if the left user has the app killed it will receive a notification and he know that a new message arrived. Basically the socket is only connecting when a specific chat discussion is opened and closed when he exit the chat viewController. In all the other cases he simply receive a notification.

Comment: You have to implement APNS in your server, I mean it's not the chat socket which send a push notification directly, but when you decode the arrived message (and probably store it in a database) you also have to check the receiver status (online/offline) and send a notification if needed. I have implemented APNS by my self in PHP but you can use available services as https://www.pushwoosh.com for instance.

Comment: It's So fine description. Thanks for the time spend for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: have you enable background mode?]

have you enable background mode in the target